# Name manager does not work with formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2003

Hey guys i am trying to do a formula based in a background color. For example if the background color is red, the value of cell multiply it by 290€.

I found this: 
[image: possible solution]

But doesn't work:

[image: show the error]

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to use an english EXCEL formula in your localized version. Use the equivalents in your language and your code will work.

According to [this site](http://www.piuha.fi/excel-function-name-translation/index.php?page=francais-english.html), you should change `OFFSET` to `SHIFT`.

Comment: In my enterprise is Catalan from Catalonia. SHIFT i think is for french?

Comment: I was just wild guessing your language. I don't see a catalan information, but for [spanish](http://www.piuha.fi/excel-function-name-translation/index.php?page=espanol-english.html) it is `DESREF`.